# Qt Creator program crash with use of taglib

Tags: c++, qt, visual-c++, crash, taglib

I have many problems with Taglib, Qt and MSVC2012

First, I compiled zlib with the cmake-gui and MSVC2012
Then, I compiled taglib with the cmake-gui and MSVC2012
After that, I opened up the .sln file in Visual Studio 2012,
then I built taglib. I got a .dll, a .lib and a .exp file. Everything good.

Then I made the following folder-structure in my Program-Folder:
My Program name is "MyM"

./MyM/taglib with all the folders inside (ape, asf, toolkit etc.)
./MyM here I have my tag.dll, my tag.lib and the "config.h" and the "taglib_config.h".

Then, in the .pro file, I added the following lines:

```
win32: LIBS += -L$$PWD/ -ltag

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/taglib
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/taglib
```

So, I built the program and it says

```
"tstring.h": No such file or directory
```

So I searched in Google for this error and I found out that I can add every folder to the INCLUDEPATH. So I did this

```
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/taglib/ape
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/taglib/asf
INCLUDEPATH += ...
```

...and so on

So, build again -> everything good!
Then I clicked the "Run"-Button and the program crashes. I don't know why and yeah. Please help me

Thank you for reading :)

Comment: Can't somebody help me? Should i recompile it? Or what should I do.

Answer (score 1):

Just resolved the same issue after struggling a little.

The taglib requires the zlib. Nothing is said about it in documentation except at the cmake stage. So if you didn't linked it here then it's quite hard to guess the cause.

Link the zlib in your .pro and it won't crash anymore.